Singularity/apptainer simulation slow down ROS2 Gazebo
Good afternoon,
I'm trying to run a Gazebo simulation of a Turtlebot4 as showed here on a singularity container. I tried also to run this example from ROS2 documentation. In the first case the real time factor is around 30% and the robot doesn't move (but data are published on the cmd_vel topic of ignition), in the second one it's around 100% and I'm able to move the robot (from outside the container by publishing into the topic from another terminal). If I run the Turtlebot4 simulation on my system, without container, the real time factor is around 100% and everything works as expected.
Someone had the same problem with singularty/apptainer containers? Do you have any idea why this could happens?
Thanks in advance

The problem was that I was running the container without the option --nv (more detail here). Running the command:
apptainer shell --nv name_of_your_image.sif
solved the problem
